# Keyring in unprivileged containers

Tags: linux, docker, security, kubernetes, encryption

Is it possible to store a password securely in a containerized Ubuntu server system *running in unprivileged mode* (running containers as root is not permitted in security-hardened platforms built on top of Kubernetes such as OCP/OKD)?

---

It seems that root permissions are used by many existing keyring implementations, for instance the [docs](https://github.com/jaraco/keyring) of the python `keyring` package state that:

> "All you need to do is [..] add the `--privileged` flag to avoid any
> Operation not permitted errors when attempting to unlock the system's
> keyring."

Comment: How secure do you need it?  The Python package you link to mentions several desktop-oriented secret managers, which probably won't be available in a Docker container.  The example there launches a DBus daemon, the GNOME password manager, and the Python client all in the same container, from an interactive shell; this would not be a typical container setup and would be especially hard to do in Kubernetes.

Comment: Yes, you are right, keyrings were not designed for such noninteractive environments, and it seems that a dedicated external password management system is needed for securing passwords without leaving them visible in the container environment.

Answer (score 0):

After some research I've found possible solution from a company recommended by Red Hat: **CyberArk Conjur** one of the open-source tools compatible with Openshift (see [docs](https://demo.openshift.com/en/latest/cyberark-for-openshift/)) for such headless (non-human) authentication of containerized applications and for storing credentials such as database passwords (including more secure methods such as REST API calls, not just Secrets injected as env vars or volumes that are then visible in the running container's shell).

Setup and maintenance are however much more costly, as Conjur involves running a dedicated cluster with several VMs.